# Python Datetime Merging all values into int

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I would like to get the datetime of the program converted to a int, What I want is:

```py
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())

> 2021-01-12 09:15:16.9791000 # the time I ran the command
```

into this:

```
> 202101120915169791000
```

How can I do this?

Comment: if you want to have datetime as a numeric value, why not use [`timestamp` (Unix time)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `strftime` format.

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
a = int(a.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
print(a)

# Output
# 20210112092900
```

If you want to get the whole nanosecond then try it

```
print(int(a.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f')))
# Output
#20210112092900275246
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use indexing or run through a it as a string.

```
import datetime
s = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
chars_list = ['-', ' ', ':', '.']
ans = ''
for c in s:
    if c not in chars_list:
        ans = ans + c
print(int(ans))
```